# How to parse/format a RSS tag full of CSS code

Tags: java, android, css, xml, rss

I'm working with the following RSS : http://aplicaciones.esi.us.es/antalumnos/rss.xml

As we can see, description tag contains the text I need and also it's full of CSS code between the text. This is a problem because once I parse the description tag I get all the CSS code as well.

The RSS link is made with drupal 6 and it cannot be changed, furthermore others RSS readers as feedly shows all the content perfectly without code between the text. How can I deal with this problem ?

```
   <description>
&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;span style=&quot;color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 13.3333px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);&quot;&gt;El pasado sábado 11 de Junio cerramos la temporada de rutas en bici organizadas por la Asociación con un recorrido de 72 Km por la conocida y espectacular Vía Verde de la Sierra. Con un día soleado y no excesivamente caluroso partimos con nuestras máquinas desde la estación de Puerto Serrano en dirección a Olvera, disfrutando de un bello y rico entorno natural fuimos avanzando con paradas en los sitios más singulares (Chaparro de la Vega, estación de Coripe, Peñón de Zaframagón y estación de Olvera. Una vez aquí retornamos al punto de partida.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;div style=&quot;padding-top: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 13.3333px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);&quot;&gt;
&lt;p&gt;A pesar de la distancia recorrida la ruta se hizo llevadera gracias a la coincidencia de varios factores como la buena compañía, la belleza del entorno, un buen firme parq rodar sin muchos desniveles y con treinta túneles en los que refrescarse a su paso.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Finalmente en el restaurante de la estación de Puerto Serrano compartimos, como de costumbre, un agradable rato para reponer energías degustando los productos de la zona.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Facilitamos algunas fotos:&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div style=&quot;color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 13.3333px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);&quot;&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div style=&quot;color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 13.3333px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);&quot;&gt;&lt;a title=&quot;http://aplicaciones.esi.us.es/antalumnos/node/3144&quot; href=&quot;http://aplicaciones.esi.us.es/antalumnos/node/3144&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; rel=&quot;noreferrer&quot; style=&quot;color: rgb(1, 134, 186);&quot;&gt;http://aplicaciones.esi.us.es/antalumnos/node/3144&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
</description>
```

Comment: How do you parse your tag? From the little I know about CSS, the code you don't want is the style. So everything between and including `style=&quot` and `&quot;` at the end is to be removed. Depending how you parse you can separate one line, find the index of the `&` and if the following 4 characters are `quot`, it is the beginning so you can put the start index 6 before the `&` (corresponding to `style=`), you search the same further, this would mark the end. You cut around the positions and you replace the line.

Comment: I'm using Simple XML framework http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php and when I parse a tag I get the full content. 

The text I need is mixed with the code and I don't know how to separate it and take just the text I want. Probably your answer is the only way to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best way to replace all occurences of `style=...`, which I presume are the CSS code parts you want removed, is to use a regular expression (regex). I use this [site](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) as a reference. Here is a little example:

```
String text = "style=&quot;hfhdjdh;&quot; YAY";
String regex = "(style=&quot;)(.*)(&quot;)";
System.out.println(text.replaceAll(regex, "replaced"));
```

This will output `replaced YAY`. Essentially, like in my comment, the regex finds places where there is `style=&quot;`, (.*) ignores anything inside and we mark the end with another `&quot;`. You just need to change the replace string with a whitespace or simply an empty string and it will remove it from your content. `replaceAll` should remove all occurences, so you don't need to search line by line.